# How to check if the keys in an object has certain value?

Tags: express, joi

I'm using Joi for validating my schema. I want to check if any one the key in that schema has certain value or not.

For example I've this schema *parking*

```
parking: Joi.object({
 twoWheelers: Joi.boolean(),
 fourWheelers: Joi.boolean(),
 handicapped: Joi.boolean(),
})
```

I want it to be valid only if any one of the keys has a value *true* to it. So if the user supply *false* for all the properties it should be invalid.

Joi has this [when](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v16.0.0-rc2/API.md#anywhencondition-options) property that i can attach to add validation based on the supplied values but I'm not sure if I can use this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for [`object.or(peers)`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectorpeers-options) ?

Defines a relationship between keys where one of the peers is required (and more than one is allowed) where:

- `peers` - the key names of which at least one must appear.
- `options` - optional settings:

  - `separator` - overrides the default . hierarchy separator. Set to `false` to treat the `key` as a literal value.

---

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    parking: Joi.object({
        twoWheelers: Joi.boolean(),
        fourWheelers: Joi.boolean(),
        handicapped: Joi.boolean(),
    }).or('twoWheelers', 'fourWheelers', 'handicapped').invalid(false)
      // or without invalid
      //.or('twoWheelers', 'fourWheelers', 'handicapped')
    smackMyPinchUp: Joi.any()
});
```

Comment: *or* only checks if one of the given property exists or not. What I want is to check whether at least one of them has true value or not. I'm not sure if you understood my question correctly  but I want the users to provide at least one the *parking type* while submitting the form